# Crudrepository findById searches by name instead of id

Tags: java, spring-boot

[image]

As you can see that i am calling findbyId but in terminal it creates SQL command as **where name=?**

how to get it fixed that it should call it as **where id=?**

```
Userrepository code

package com.appzat.carpious.repositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.appzat.carpious.models.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

}


User Code

package com.appzat.carpious.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
private Integer Id;
    @jakarta.persistence.Id

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;

    private String email;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.first_name = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.last_name = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirst_name(){
        return this.first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name(){
        return this.last_name;
    }
}
***
```

Comment: You've been on this site long enough to know that you should not be posting pictures of code. Just cut and paste the code in question. You should also know to post the necessary code, preferably as a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). With what you've provided, how are we supposed to know anything about your repository implementation? Or the implementation of findById? Or how you're calling it? By now, you should know better. No info = no help.

Comment: Please share the code of following classes: User and UserRepository.

Comment: Userrepository code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

1. Change this:

```java
private Integer Id;
    @jakarta.persistence.Id
```

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;

    @Id
    private Integer Id;
```

2. And this:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>
```

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>
```